# DBCC DBREINDEX in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, index, t-sql

We have done `DBCC DBREINDEX` for our production database which size is about 300 gb, it was running for 12+ hours, but i found that `DBCC DBREINDEX` is obsolete and recommended approach is using `ALTER INDEX` command with rebuild, also, we have performance problems right now with database, could it be related to using old method for reindexing ? We have MS SQL Server 2008 (11.2)

Comment: did the dbcc dbreindex finish or did you kill it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it states on the `ALTER INDEX` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx), using `ALTER INDEX ...REBUILD` is **equivalent to DBCC DBREINDEX**.

`ALTER INDEX` has far more functionality in terms of other arguments and `DBCC DBREINDEX` is deprecated, however the performance issues you face should not  be related to using the old method of re-indexing.